# Starvation in `asyncio` loop

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a system where two "processes" `A` and `B` run on the same `asyncio` event loop.

I notice that the order of the initiation of processes matters - i.e. if I start process `B` first then process `B` runs all the time, while it seems that `A` is being "starved" of resources vise-a-versa.

In my experience, the only reason this might happen is due to a `mutex` which is not being released by `B`, but in the following toy example it happens without any `mutex`s being used:

```
import asyncio


async def A():
    while True:
        print('A')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)


async def B():
    while True:
        print('B')
        await asyncio.sleep(8)


async def main():
    await B()
    await A()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Is in `python` the processes do not perform context-switch automatically? If not - how can I make both processes participate, each one in the time the other one is idle (i.e., sleeping)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: Coroutines merely *enable* concurrency, they do not automatically *trigger* concurrency. Explicitly launch separate tasks, e.g. via `create_task` or `gather`, to run the coroutines concurrently.

```py
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(B(), A())
```

---

Concurrency in `asyncio` is handled via Tasks – a close equivalent to Threads – which merely *consist of* coroutines/awaitables – like Threads *consist of* functions/callables. In general, a coroutine/awaitable itself does not equate to a separate task.

Using `await X()` means "start `X` and *wait for it to complete*". When using several such constructs in sequence:

```py
async def main():
    await B()
    await A()
```

this means launching `B` first, and only launching `A` after `B` has completed: while `async def` and `await` allows for concurrency *towards other tasks*, `B` and `A` are run sequentially with respect to each other *in a single task*.

The simplest means to add concurrency is to explicitly create a task:

```py
async def main():
    # execute B in a new task
    b_task = asyncio.create_task(B())
    # execute A in the current task
    await A()
    await b_task
```

Note how `B` is offloaded to a new task, while one can still do a final `await A()` to re-use the current task.

Most async frameworks ship with high-level helpers for common concurrency scenarios. In this case, `asyncio.gather` is appropriate to launch several tasks at once:

```py
async def main():
    # execute B and A in new tasks
    await asyncio.gather(B(), A())
```